# How to reset default brightness, if application crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my application I was trying to apply full brightness to my view and also store current brightness in one variable, so as soon as my application state become background/resign-activity I was reset default brightness, now My question is that in case of my application crash What event I get to reset default brightness, there is any method which is call with application crash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why down vote ? need explanation..

Comment: what's the hell of is this, Why Down code...? No one can ask question like this before now.... and it's one kind of exception handling... may be some one have poor knowledge...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

catch most cases using

1. appWillTerminate
2. exception handler
3. signal handler

during didFinishLaunching install the needed handlers

```
// installs HandleExceptions as the Uncaught Exception Handler
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler(&HandleExceptions);
// create the signal action structure
struct sigaction newSignalAction;
// initialize the signal action structure
memset(&newSignalAction, 0, sizeof(newSignalAction));
// set SignalHandler as the handler in the signal action structure
newSignalAction.sa_handler = &SignalHandler;
// set SignalHandler as the handlers for SIGABRT, SIGILL and SIGBUS
sigaction(SIGABRT, &newSignalAction, NULL);
sigaction(SIGILL, &newSignalAction, NULL);
sigaction(SIGBUS, &newSignalAction, NULL);
```

then you have

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
  // Write your code to reset brightness
}

void HandleExceptions(NSException *exception) {
    DebugLog(@"This is where we save the application data during a exception");
    // Save application data on crash
  // Write your code to reset brightness
}

void SignalHandler(int sig) {
    DebugLog(@"This is where we save the application data during a signal");
    // Save application data on crash
  // Write your code to reset brightness
}
```

Comment: Thanks dude, but need more help that I was call one method to store default brightness value for that I need to write [self methodname] but self is not working why ?

Comment: Wow, this is a really interesting answer.

Comment: Note that it's _very dangerous_ to do any work in a signal handler, certainly not safe to call Objective-C methods. It could be invoked from inside malloc while the internal heap data structures are corrupted, etc. Here's a list of the only functions that are safe to call: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-5257/gen-26/index.html.

Comment: (or http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html, look for “Async-signal-safe functions”) Also, Mike Ash has an intro to a more Mach-appropriate API, not sure if it's working well on iOS or not: https://mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-01-11-mach-exception-handlers.html

Answer (score 3):

You can put a try/catch block in your main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

int retVal = 0;
@try {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"NightLightAppDelegate");
    [pool release];
} @catch (id any) {
    //-- reset brightness
}
return retVal;
}
```

and reset brightness in the catch block.

You would also need, however to reset brightness in case the app is terminated (which is not called often, actually), and when it enters background:

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    ....
}

-(void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication*)application {
   ...
}
```

Comment: yip that will at least get all exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

in app delegate class implementation 
add one method

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application;
{
  // Write your code to reset brightness
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this will not always be called and it's not possible to catch all cases in which the App will terminate.

Comment: This will not call...agree with @JoeyClover

Comment: I dont, this combined with catching 99% of the crashes makes it almost good